# last modified date in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am wondering how can I make a javascript function that will return the date and time the HTML/PHP file was last modified.

I found this on W3, but the button has to be clicked in order for the script to run.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.lastModified;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to get it to run when something is changed on the file. As I'm typing this I think it is a lot more difficult than I thought, and what I'm thinking of might not even be possible. But, I am not great with JS so I would like some input before just changing the last modified date for my site manually each time I update it.

Thanks!

EDIT: Would something like this work?

```
<script>

setInterval(function modify() {
var x = document.lastModified;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x}, 86400000);

}
</script>
```

Comment: You would need to call a function that calls a php script on an interval to get the modification date

Comment: @BasSlats so would something like this work?    
    <script>
    setInterval(function modify() {
    var x = document.lastModified;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x}, 86400000);

    }
    </script>

Comment: @BasSlats sorry for the bad formatting. Not too good at this yet

Comment: Read the comment by @Bas Slats. document.lastModified tells you when the browser document was last modified. If you want to know about the PHP file you'll need to ask the host.

Comment: @bobdye and can that be done with a javascript function? Basically what it's sounding like is it will be easier for me just to change it manually each time I update it

Comment: It would require both Javascript (to make an Ajax call) and PHP (to accept the call, get the answer, and return it).

Comment: What do you mean by “the HTML/PHP file was last modified”? A PHP file and an HTML file generated from it by a PHP processor are two different beasts. And do you mean that some information on a page would change immediately or within some period of time if the PHP file is changed *while the user is viewing the page*? Are you sure you want this?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela what I meant was, if I update any part of the file. HTML or PHP file. Anything I change in the file. I want some script to realize when I updated and made those changed and output the date. After looking further into it, I realize that this seems very difficult to do and I'm most likely better off doing it manually.